# Autodesk Platform Services Access Token

Tags: oauth, autodesk-forge

Following Autodesk's APS 2-legged Authentication documentation, where I should be calling the POST token endpoint in the APS tutorial for the simple viewer.

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs

Currently the code produces an errorCode of Auth-001, "client_id specified does not have access to the api product":

[Error Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hovXI.png)

[Error Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InDlN.png)

The errorCode does not make sense, I have double checked my client_id so the problem likely lies somewhere else.

The example uploaded on github does not contain any of the additional lines of code on the getAccessToken() function as shown in the code below.

```
async function getAccessToken(callback) {
    try {
        const clientId = "<____________________________________________________>"
        const clientSecret = "<________________________________________________>"

        // Base64 encode the client ID and client secret
        const concatword = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
        const base64word = btoa(concatword);

        const url = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token';
        const body = new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'scope': 'data:read'
        });

        const resp = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64word
            },
            body: body
        });
```

Where am I going wrong. Code on github:
https://github.com/retug/APSExamples/tree/main/simpleViewer

Answer (score 1):

You error indicates that you are trying to access an API which you did not authorize.
This has nothing to do with authentication but rather API authorization.

Kindly have a look at how to create your app and setup credentials at https://tutorials.autodesk.io/#create-app-credentials

Answer (score 0):

Resolved error by removing "<" and ">" from from clientId and clientSecret string.

Comment: Just removing the `<` or `>` chars from credentials doesn't look like a viable solution. Didn't you rather replace the full placeholders (including `<` and `>`) with the real credentials?